# Hyperlink does not clickable in the Datatables (Asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, hyperlink, datatables

My web-page has a DataTable which contains some data from the database and two hyperlinks (Update, Delete) option.

I created These two HyperLinks using asp.  But they are not clickable means (they are not working as a hyperlink) but I want to do update or delete the information using the 'id' from DB which store in *selectedHiddenId*

```
        **dataTable body code is given below**

          <tbody>
        <%
            foreach (Student student in Students)
            {
                string selectedHiddenId = student.Id.ToString();
                Response.Write(selectedHiddenId);
        %>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><% Response.Write(student.Name); %>
                
                <asp:HiddenField ID="idHiddenField" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td><% Response.Write(student.Class); %></td>
            <td class="text-center"><% Response.Write(student.Section); %></td>
            <td class="text-center"><% Response.Write(student.RegistrationNumber); %></td>
            <td class="text-center"><% Response.Write(student.FatherContuctNumber); %></td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="updateHyperLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Concat("~/UI/StudentUpdate.aspx?id=",Eval("selectedHiddenId")) %>'>Update</asp:HyperLink></td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="deleteHyperLink" runat="server">Delete</asp:HyperLink></td>
        </tr>
        <%
                                    } %>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: See this to upload and display images - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700715/upload-2-different-files-to-2-different-destinations-in-table-and-folders/39700913#39700913

Comment: There has GOT to be a way to simplify this code to show the nature of your problem, yes? There is a lot of extra stuff in here.

Comment: Read up on SQL injections...

Comment: When you code runs do the cells have hyperlinks? What do you see? I'm not up on ASP but I'd be inclined to have all the data within the object that DataTables processes and get DT to create the hyperlink. You can have the HiddenId as a cell that isn't displayed...

Comment: @annoyingmouse Sorry for late. Yes datatable cells have hyperlinks . But when i move cursor in the Delete or Update hyperlink it show likes( | ). Not clickable. Can you help me ?

Comment: Something like this might work: https://snipt.net/annoyingmouse/tableasp/?key=0239f75f2d1735357c53862610be2418 But I'm not up on asp stuff so I might be wrong. Alternatively, you could just duplicate the ID in the last two rows and get the DataTable to generate the correct URL for the Update and Delete actions.

Comment: @annoyingmouse Thank's it's work.